# webserver for file upload on android

Tags: android, webserver, embeddedwebserver

I would like to add a webserver to my android application for uploading small files to the phone.

The user would start the webserver from the phone by hitting a button. He would then see an ip address that can be accessed by any browser from a pc. The website behind this ip address should show a file upload opportunity.

**My question is:** Is there an open source project similar to my needs? Or how would you recommend doing this?

Comment: isnt that what WebDAV already does?.. Why would you need an alternate copy.

Comment: need ur help getting out of question ban upvote this http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/18403488/cannot-connect-to-my-android-phone please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use NanoHttpd [link](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd) it's very weight android web server that is nicely embbedible..

```
package .....;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Properties;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidWebServerActivity extends Activity {
private static final int PORT = 8765;
private TextView hello;
private MyHTTPD server;
private Handler handler = new Handler();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();

try {
server = new MyHTTPD();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
super.onPause();
if (server != null)
server.stop();
}

private class MyHTTPD extends NanoHTTPD {
public MyHTTPD() throws IOException {
super(PORT, null);
}

@Override
public Response serve(String uri, String method, Properties header, Properties parms, Properties files) {
final StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
for (Entry<Object, Object> kv : header.entrySet())
buf.append(kv.getKey() + " : " + kv.getValue() + "\n");
handler.post(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {

}
});

final String html = "<html><head><head><body><h1>Hello, World</h1></body></html>";
return new NanoHTTPD.Response(HTTP_OK, MIME_HTML, html);
}
}
}
```